# Compiler action

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

In my C# VS2013 Express project I have  a file that I want to compile at runtime.
How can I tell compiler to include this file as text in Resources so It will be embedded in exe and I won't have to distribute the source of the file with application.

I want compiler to take the action of embeding the file as resource into string,
so during development I will have all functionality of Visual Studio with working with code in the file.

BR
Wojtek

Comment: which type of project you have  ? winforms wpf console ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click either the file , and then select Properties.
2. In the Properties dialog box, locate the Build Action property. By default, this property is set to Content. Click the property and change the Build Action property to Embedded Resource.

In you code you can access the resource as show in below code snippet.

```
  try
   {
      var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

      var textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt"));
   }
   catch
   {

   }
```